# mutually include/exclude options in python's argparse

Tags: python-2.7, argparse

How to describe the following arguments syntax for python's argparse

**'-l'** -> discards all other options (like '-h')

OR

one of `['-w','-r','-v']` with mandatory **file**

Comment: You need to add mutually exclusive argument groups, try looking at the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#mutual-exclusion) and let us know if you have specific difficulties implementing.

Comment: @Eric, how to combine a flag, for e.g. -l, with group of flags with mandatory argument, for e.g. (-w,-r,-v) file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) module is very flexible, you should look at using groups or sub-parsers to accomplish your goals natively.

However, if you just want to hack together something, then you can handle your own conditions:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
for arg in ["-l", "-w", "-r", "-v"]:
    parser.add_argument(arg, action="store_true")
parser.add_argument("--file", nargs=1)
args = parser.parse_args("-l --file foo.txt".split())
print args
args = parser.parse_args("-l -r".split())
print args
if any((args.w, args.r, args.v)) and args.file is None:
    parser.error("w r v arguments require a file")
```

This will print:

```
Namespace(file=['foo.txt'], l=True, r=False, v=False, w=False)
Namespace(file=None, l=True, r=True, v=False, w=False)
usage: arg_parse_test.py [-h] [-l] [-w] [-r] [-v] [--file FILE]
arg_parse_test.py: error: w r v arguments require a file
```